# How do I convert a .pcm file into a wav file with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, audio, discord.js

I made a code that creates a pcm file out of a stream and saves it after the stream ended. I need to convert this .pcm file into a .wav or any other audio file if possible. Is there some kind of npm package that would help me out on this problem?

Comment: Please be aware that asking for packages, tools, or libraries if ott-topic. That said: you probably need to use an audio conversion tool, like ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple [audiobuffer-to-wav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audiobuffer-to-wav) npm.
You could look into using that.

Comment: Please may you flag the question as off topic?

Comment: i have buffer, can i directly convert and save to wav?  if u can help on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73373344/0xc00d36c4-while-saving-file-to-wav-format-nodejs-amazon-polly-text-to-speech