# 0xc00d36c4 while saving file to wav format nodejs amazon polly text to speech

Tags: node.js, stream, wav, amazon-polly, node.js-fs

I am using Amazon polly for text to speech.

Here is the code

```
static async _ttsUsingPolly(text, gender, destPath, speed) {
    let params = {
        'Text': 'Hi, my name is @anaptfox.',
        'OutputFormat': 'pcm',
        'VoiceId': 'Kimberly',
        SampleRate: "8000"
    }
    const data = await this.Polly.synthesizeSpeech(params).promise();

    if (data.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
        console.log("buffer", data);
        // Initiate the source
        const bufferStream = new Stream.PassThrough();
        // convert AudioStream into a readable stream
        bufferStream.end(data.AudioStream);
        // Pipe into Player
        bufferStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destPath));
    }
}
```

this saves the file to .wav format. `destPath` is **public\audio\abc\1212_1660649369899.wav**.

But when i play this file it says

```
This file isn’t playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt.

0xc00d36c4
```

what is the issue (if someone can explain)? and how can i fix this?

**Update1**

actually this generates the pcm format file, so i tried wav converter

```
var pcmData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './audios/audio_wav', fileName))
        var wavData = wavConverter.encodeWav(pcmData, {
            numChannels: 1,
            sampleRate: 8000,
            byteRate: 16
        })

        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './audios/audio_wav', './16k.wav'), wavData)
```

pcm generated file is of almost 67KB but converted wav file is of 1KB.

if i change pcm to mp3 in polly params it works.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I directly passed the stream to `wav-converter`

```
._convertPcmToWav(data.AudioStream, fileName);
```

and

```
static _convertPcmToWav(stream, fileName) {
        const wavData = wavConverter.encodeWav(stream, {
            numChannels: 1,
            sampleRate: 8000,
            byteRate: 2
        });
        const wavFileName = path.parse(fileName).name;
        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './audios/audio_wav', `./${wavFileName}.wav`), wavData)
    }
```

now the file is generated correctly and playable.